# Where in Toronto can I rent a mailbox to receive packages with a street address?

Tags: postal-system

I move around a lot so I need an address to get stuff & I'm having trouble finding a mailbox service rental that: accepts packages as long as they are open; 24hr access to the box; in downtown Toronto with only one number in the street address!...

UPS has everything I need but all their addresses look like 12-146 blah blah St. which can confuse computer systems...because after the 12-146 you still have to add in your suite number so it makes it obvious this is not a "real" address...so are there any package receiving services in Toronto  that fit my needs?

I don't a have house address or a friends' place for this.

Comment: 12-246 may be a real address.  For example in Fair Lawn, NJ houses (real ones) can have address of 12-21 <street>

Comment: It's worth rewording to make it clear you don't live there - otherwise this sounds like just a problem that anyone might encounter, including people living in the Toronto area.

Answer (score 1):

The UPS Store seems to be offering [everything you are asking for](http://theupsstore.ca/services/mailboxes/). From their website:

> Here’s what you get with mailbox rental:
>
> A street address, not a P.O. Box number
>
> Package acceptance from all shipping carriers
>
> Mail holding and forwarding
>
> 24-hour access (additional fees apply)

(And some other stuff I removed because it's marketing.)

As an alternative, you could use [a virtual office/business center](http://www.telsec.net/), but you might not have 24-hour access. They will forward mail to you, however.

Comment: Clicking "What does my mailing address look like?" on that page reveals that the address includes the mailbox number, which the asker specifically wants to avoid.

Comment: Ah! In that case, just write "Suite ###" where ### is the mailbox number. ;)

Comment: "Only one number in the street address."

Comment: OP? Any comments? You will know your acceptance criteria better than we will. Also, does the virtual office have the same issue? Mine doesn't. I just put my name and the actual street address for the virtual office.